# Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime can not be installed in Xamarin PCL Project

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin

I tried to add **Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime v2.3.10** via **Nuget** to a **standard Xamarin PCL project** and got following error:

*Could not install package 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime 2.3.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.*

The targets for the project as as follows:

[image]

Comment: the package doesn't support PCL

Comment: The error is as descriptive as it can be: the library isn't compatible with .NETPortable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was just to install version 2.0.0 of Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, which is portable.